# Can i use rak command inside rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I have install gem rak i want to use rak command inside rake task ...

How may i use that ??

I know how to use it on command prompt ...

This is working fine on command prompt ...

rak RAILS_ENV

Comment: do you mean rack or rake when you say "rak"

Comment: @rogerdpack rak is a gem .rak is a replacement of grep ... If i write rak RAILS_ENV on my command prompt than it will display all the files with the line number which containing RAILS_ENV...

Comment: Like rogerdpack, I thought that "rak" was a mis-spelling. I think the poor grammar in your question made me think that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links may help you run command line command into ruby ...

http://zhangxh.net/programming/ruby/6-ways-to-run-shell-commands-in-ruby/

[Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html

```
%x[command].each do |f|
  value = f
end
```

Answer (score 0):

to run 'rak' you can either run it as a command, like

```
 a = `rak asdf`
```

ref: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes

or hack into the rak source code and figure out how to call it.