# How to execute commands within Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, command-line, rake, rake-task

I have the rake tasks in my rails application. i want to run a commandline commands with in rake task. how can i do this. i tried by the following but fails

```
desc "Sending the newsletter to all the users"
task :sending_mail do
  run "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && ar_sendmail -o -t NewsLetters -v"
  system "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && ar_sendmail -o -t NewsLetters -v &"
end
```

The above run command throws run method undefined & System command not throwing any errors but not executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This links may help you run command line command into ruby ...

http://zhangxh.net/programming/ruby/6-ways-to-run-shell-commands-in-ruby/

[Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html

```
%x[command].each do |f|
  value = f
end
```

Comment: Rake has a specific method for running a shell command, `#sh`. It has the shortcoming of using `/bin/sh`, not bash however.To use bash from Rake's `sh` method, see this answer to a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796028/execute-bash-commands-from-a-rakefile/34523379#34523379

Answer (score 29):

**Rake [`sh`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/rake/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-i-sh)  built-in task**

This is probably the best method:

```
task(:sh) do
  sh('echo', 'a')
  sh('false')
  sh('echo', 'b')
end
```

The interface is similar to `Kernel.system` but:

- it aborts if the return is != 0, so the above never reaches `echo b`
- the command itself is echoed before the output

Comment: Seems like the best method to me too

Answer (score 7):

`run` is used by Capistrano and other things for launching commands, but Rake often makes use of `Kernel#system` instead.

Your command might be being run, but not working. Why not make a wrapper shell script you can test independently, or try and kick off using the full path:

```
newsletter_script = File.expand_path('ar_sendmail', RAILS_ROOT)

if (File.exist?(newsletter_script))
  unless (system(newsletter_script + ' -o -t NewsLetters -v &'))
    STDERR.puts("Script #{newsletter_script} returned error condition")
  end
else
  STDERR.puts("Could not find newsletter sending script #{newsletter_script}")
end
```

It would seem odd to have your script not in `scripts/`

The `system` call should return `true` on success. If this is not the case, either the script returned an error code, or the command could't be run.

Comment: Hi tadman, Thanks for your answer... i just copied your code and tried but not working as expected..can you please tell me what is File.expand_path do ?

Comment: Hello tadman, your script looking for the file Rails_Root/ar_sendmailer. but this is not a file and this is command which invoked from Rails app root folder. like [/home/username/railsapp]$ar_sendmail -o -t NewLetter -V . so i rake file i go the Rails application root folder and trigger the above command that what i need... please help me on this

Comment: `File.expand_path` is used to...expand paths, basically. It will properly join two paths together, like appending `ar_sendmail` on your Rails path, whatever that is. It's also good for eliminating things like `../../` when required, giving you the proper, full path.

Comment: You need to know where `ar_sendmail` is otherwise you won't be able to launch it properly. Your shell has a `PATH` which can differ from what Ruby will use, and that can make scripts work even when they're not in the directory you're in.