# How do I run a batch file with Admin privileges in Windows?

Tags: ruby, rake, albacore

I am using Albacore and I want to run a batch file that needs to be elevated as Administrator.
The rights are checked as:

**Batch file:**

```
AT > NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO AdminRightError

:: more code here

:AdminRightError
ECHO You are not running as administrator!
```

**Rakefile:**

```
exec :CmdRunBatch do |cmd|
  cmd.command = "RunCommands.bat"
end
```

When I execute `rake CmdRunBatch` through a normal (non-elevated) command-line I get the AdminRightError described in the batch file. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not following, I expect the rake task to fail in a normal prompt... are you asking how to elevate a command? I changed the question title to reflect that, hope I'm right :)

Comment: I'm curious, if you try to run as admin, a UAC dialog will appear. You'll have to dismiss it. Unless you have UAC off, in which case, you're already admin. Is this running on a build-server or manually on your local machine?

Comment: I refer you to another answer I just provided: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18902122/3619

Comment: Anthony, thanks for the comments! I do this:
Run visual studio 2012 with the 'Rake Runner' extension.
My script needs elevation but because VS is not elevated, the script fails. Is there a way to ask for UAC elevation when I run the script?
-Edit: I think your answer is giving some insight, I will check!