# Deploying Jekyll with a rakefile & rsync

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rakefile

I'm running into trouble trying to use a rakefile to deploy a Jekyll site. Following the instructions [here](http://www.layouts-the.me/rake/2011/04/23/rake_tasks_for_jekyll/), I've set up ssh keys and can get into my server without entering a password, so that works. However, when I try to run a test sync (e.g, rake deploy dry-run) I get an error. I've added rakefile.rb to my repo but when I try to run it I get an error:

```
rake deploy:dryrun --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:dryrun'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/Christopher/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/rake:37:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ``Don't know how to build task 'deploy:dryrun'``: something is missing in your rakefile.

Comment: My rakefile is [here](https://github.com/chrisfinazzo/chrisfinazzo.com/blob/master/rakefile.rb) if you want to take a look. I've gotten it to run, but I don't see any of the options (like --progress) that I specified.

Comment: Try ``rake rsync:dryrun`` or ``rake rsync:deploy``. Dose it work?

Comment: The commands run, and will print the various `puts` steps I've included (to have some idea of how things are going), but I don't see the options I added to the file e.g `--progress` or `--verbose`, so it's hard to tell if anything is actually being transferred.

Comment: I think this post might be of some help: [bach command in rakefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796028/execute-bash-commands-from-a-rakefile). The bash command should be enclosed included `` `  `` (backtick) instead of ``'``.