# Running foreman from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, foreman

I have the following Rake task:

```
namespace :foreman do
  task :dev do
    `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`
  end
end

desc "Run Foreman using Procfile.dev"
task :foreman => 'foreman:dev'
```

The forman command works fine from the shell, however when I run `rake foreman` I get the following error:

```
/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:240:in `block in replace_gem': foreman is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/foreman:22:in `<main>'
```

Forman specifically states:

```
Ruby users should take care not to install foreman in their project's Gemfile
```

**So how can I get this task to run?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must make it work via rake, try changing the shell-out via backtick to use a hard-coded path to the system-wide foreman binary

```
`/global/path/to/foreman start -f Procfile.dev`
```

You just need to use 'which' or 'locate' or a similar tool to determine the path that works outside your bundler context. If you are using rbenv, then this might be sufficient :

```
$ rbenv which rake
/home/name/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/rake
```

I hope that helps you move forward.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work, but you could export the environment variables associated with your shell explicitly and then make a call to `foreman`. FWIW, I don't think this is recommended, and would suggest using a bash script as @dax proposes.

Steps

1. Get the `$PATH` and other environment variables from your shell

   ```
   printenv >> shell.env
   ```
2. Get the environment variables from the rails environment

   ```
   namespace :foreman_test do
     task :dev do
       `printenv >> rails.env`
     end
   end
   ```
3. Compare the two and find out the changed environment variables, and set them up in your rake task in the `system` call

   ```
   namespace :foreman do
     task :dev do
       `export PATH=/original/path:/value && GEM_DIR=/some/folder && foreman start -f Procfile.dev`
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please can you explain why running it from the rake task is failing? Given that the task doesn't rely on `:environment` why exactly is it going through the bundle?

Comment: @Pedr One explanation is that you initialized your repo with `--binstubs`, and so when you execute `rake taskname`, you are actually using `bin/rake`, and your `GEMFILE` is picked by default. Anyway, did my solution work?

Comment: I don't use binstubs. I use a `be` alias instead. I've tried running `rake`, `be rake` and `bin/rake`. All result in the same error I described above. I can't test at the moment, but I'll try as soon as I can.

Comment: @Pedr if you run it as `be rake`, you are already invoking the bundler, which means the Gemfile for the project is going to be anyway referred. Since you mention using `bin/rake`, I think it's safe to assume that `rake` will also refer to `bin/rake`. So in either case, your Gemfile is being referred. Since a system call will initiate a new sub process, it will be safe to export the variables/ reset them within the subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

if it has to be a rake task, try this (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360488/2128691)):

```
namespace :foreman do
  task :dev do
    sh "foreman start -f Procfile.dev"
  end
end
```

if it doesn't *have* to be a rake task, I have a simple bash script to start for a specific project that works well:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PROJECT_DIR=`pwd`
export PORT=$1

source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE
unset BUNDLE_BIN_PATH
unset RUBYOPT
unset GEM_HOME
unset GEM_PATH

(cd <project full path> && exec foreman start -p $PORT)
```

Comment: Thanks, think I'd prefer to keep everything in tasks (have a lot already). Unfortunately using `sh` or `system` in the task gets me the same error.

Comment: maybe that warning is to not install in the project gemfile - is it installed/have you tried installing it in your global gemfile?

Comment: It's definitely available to the system. I can run `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` without `bundle exec` and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

A little way down the line and here is how I do it suing chruby:

```
namespace :foreman do
  task :dev do
    # 1. Load .bash_profile to ensure chruby is available
    # 2. Switch the ruby version to the one defined in .ruby-version
    # 3. Start foreman
    system %(
      source ~/.bash_profile
      chruby "$(cat .ruby-version)"
      foreman start --procfile Procfile.dev
    )
  end
end

desc "Run Foreman using Procfile.dev"
task :foreman => 'foreman:dev'
```