# Ruby rescue and abort

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling, rake, rescue

I am seeing this pattern in someone else's Rakefile:

```
begin
  sh "..."
rescue
  abort
end
```

What's the author doing here? Why rescue if I'm going to abort anyway? Do I understand correctly that this *mutes* the potential shell error?

I am new to ruby and rake. As far as I understand, the `sh` is rake's shorthand for `FileUtils.sh()` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360488/1540600)). And `FileUtils.sh()` may raise a `RuntimeError` ([ref](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/rake/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-i-sh)).

Does this mean that we are effectively throwing away the information/message in the `RuntimeError` and exiting rake with an error status, but without a specific error message? Is this a rake/ruby pattern? Any recommended reading?

Comment: This looks like pretty sloppy code to be honest. It's eating all exceptions, regardless of origin, and then blowing up in a different way. It'd be better to interpret specific exceptions and show a more meaningful error.

Comment: I would consider this being a code smell...

Comment: As *tadman* mentioned, `abort` should provide a meaningful message. See, for example: [Write a simple, clean error message without a backtrace and exit on failure - Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285164/write-a-simple-clean-error-message-without-a-backtrace-and-exit-on-failure)