# How to execute linux command from rakefile?

Tags: ruby, linux, rake-task, rakefile

I have the following command:

`ps -ef | awk '{if( $8~"java" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god"){printf("Killing : %s \n",$2);{system("kill -9 "$2)};}};'`

How do i excute this linux command from rakeFile.

I tried:

```
task :kill_process do
  `ps -ef | awk '{if( $8~"java" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god"){printf("Killing : %s \n",$2);{system("kill -9 "$2)};}};'`
end
```

But on executing it's giving error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( $8~"java" || $8~"glassfish" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god" || $8~"couch"){printf("Killing : %s 
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                 ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( $8~"java" || $8~"glassfish" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god" || $8~"couch"){printf("Killing : %s 
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                 ^ syntax error
```

I got the solution for my problem:
Thanks to @Yurii Verbytskyi

```
task :kill_process do
   system %q(ps -ef | awk '{if( $8~"java" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god"){printf("Killing : %s \n",$2);{system("kill -9 "$2)};}}') 
end
```

Comment: Does this command run directly on the command line? It appears to contain some ruby method calls.

Comment: This works fine directly on command line.

Comment: you can try https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system 
task :kill_process do
  system %q(ps -ef | awk '{if( $8~"java" || $8~"ruby" || $8~"god"){printf("Killing : %s \n",$2);}}')
end
* I removed kill command to test it locally)

Comment: @YuriiVerbytskyi thanks, it is working. Can u please tell me what is %q here

Comment: https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/ this is alternative single quotes syntax. Just used it because of different quotes are present in your command string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute bash commands from a Rakefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796028/execute-bash-commands-from-a-rakefile)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
task :kill_process do
   system("ps -ef | awk '{if( $8~\"java\" || $8~\"ruby\" || $8~\"god\"){printf(\"Killing : %s \\n\",$2);{system(\"kill -9 \"$2)};}};'")
end
```

We need to escape special chars like `\n`

Comment: What if i don't want the returned value of system method. Is there any way, not to get the returned value?

Comment: Here you can use your code as well. But the problem with ur code is escaping special characters. If you do that ur code also works fine.