# Run Ceedling from Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rake, ceedling

I am using ceedling to write unit tests. I also utilize a rakefile at the top level of my project to automate a variety of tasks. I would like to also use it to automate running ceedling. When I attempt to do so, there seems to be a conflict between my rakefile and ceedling.

I have the following project structure:

```
Project
  -> src
    -> project.yml
    -> test
    -> src.c
    -> src.h
    -> build
  -> rakefile.rb
  -> build
```

My rakefile has a command that does the following:

```
desc "Run Unit Test"
task :unit do
   Dir.chdir('src') do
      sh "ceedling test:all"
   end
end
```

When I execute this rake command, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Required config file entry [:tools][:test_compiler][:executable] does not exist.
ERROR: Required config file entry [:tools][:test_file_preprocessor][:executable] does not exist.
ERROR: Required config file entry [:tools][:test_includes_preprocessor][:executable] does not exist.
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/configurator.rb:309:in `validate': unhandled exception
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/setupinator.rb:32:in `do_setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/rakefile.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling.rb:66:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling.rb:66:in `load_project'
    from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:329:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/ceedling:25:in `load
```

EDIT: Native shell is bash, but I have tried a variety of ruby calls to run the bash command such as the following:

- sh
- %x
- system

I tried a lot defined in [Execute bash commands from a Rakefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796028/execute-bash-commands-from-a-rakefile)

Comment: The first question is does manually running `ceedling test:all` in the `src` directory work or not?

Comment: It does work manually

Comment: What's your shell? Note that the `sh` command runs using `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Do you have an env variable that's giving ceedling access to it's config file that the rakefile isn't providing?

Comment: Are you asking if there is some shell environment variable that Ceedling requires, but the rake file does not provide?

Comment: The error you're receiving makes me think ceedling can't find it's configuration file. Since it works in your local shell but not inside rake, I'm wondering if there's some PATH variable or something you have locally that is helping ceedling find it's config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the folks that left comments definitely steered me in the right direction. Turns out by defining [:tools] test_compiler in my project.yml and using system "ceedling test:all" instead of sh "ceedling test:all" executes the tests. I'm not sure why I have to define the ceedling compiler options, but I think Chiperific was on the right track. Running from a rakefile may not have the environment variables that Ceedling expects.