# Display terminal output on web browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, web-applications, webserver

Here is my case:

I want to use a web browser to connect to a Rails application that runs this example code on the server side:

```
Dir.chdir path_typed_in_by_user
system "ls -la"
```

I want the output of "ls -la" to be displayed on the web browser.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This links may help you run command line command into ruby ...

http://zhangxh.net/programming/ruby/6-ways-to-run-shell-commands-in-ruby/

[Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html

```
%x[command].each do |f|
  value = f
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try in a controller:

```
Dir.chdir path_typed_in_by_user
@out = system `ls -la` # !! look here !! " change `
```

in a view:

Comment: I think you got it wrong. It's system "ls -la". And maybe it's better to put it in a model instead to keep the controllers thin?