# Prawn templates not working

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I´m trying this simple script:

```
require 'prawn'

template_file_name = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'template.pdf')
pdf_file = Prawn::Document.new(:template => template_file_name)
pdf_file.text('Hello World')
pdf_file.render_file('output.pdf')
```

There is a template.pdf file in the same dir as the script but the output.pdf comes only with the Hello Wordl

Is there anything else that I should be concerned of?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates were introduced only in [prawn 0.10.1](https://github.com/sandal/prawn) as stated by Daniel Nelson [here](http://groups.google.com/group/prawn-ruby/browse_thread/thread/24ab992d078103ab).

Comment: I have Prawn 0.12.0 and am experiancing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stamp a pdf file with another, and you are using Ubuntu, then try installing **pdftk**.

Go to a terminal and type this:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Then go to the pdf directory and type:

```
pdftk content.pdf stamp template.pdf output final.pdf
```

If you want to do all this within Ruby, you can learn about: [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

I read about this solution in this link: http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2011/10/06/stamp-pdfs-with-prawn-and-pdftk/