# Is there a way to check if a Ruby variable contains binary data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, binary, ms-office

I'm using Ruby 2.4 and Rails 5.  I have file content in a variabe named "content".  The content could contain data from things like a PDF file, a Word file, or an HTML file.  Is there any way to tell if the variable contains binary data?  Ultimately, I would like to know if this is a PDf, Microsoft Office, or some other type of OpenOffice file.  This answer -- [Rails: possible to check if a string is binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622095/rails-possible-to-check-if-a-string-is-binary) -- suggests that I can check the encoding of the variable

```
content.encoding
```

and it would produce

```
ASCII-8BIT
```

in the case of binary data, however, I've noticed there are cases where HTML content stored in the variable could also return "ASCII-8BIT" as the content.encoding, so using "content.encoding" is not a foolproof way to tell me if I have binary data.  Does such a way exist and if so, what is it?

Comment: Given your requirements, It seems like you're gonna have to do some analysis of the content. I'd pull the top n bytes and check them against your standard ASCII codes. If many of the characters you encounter aren't ASCII, it's likely that your content is binary. Seems like a chi-squared test may be a good fit. Why can't you get access to the actual file object?

Comment: I'm accessing the content from a database in which there is no additional information about the file.  Sometimes there is a file name, but extensions are unreliable for determining file/content type.

Comment: Wait, the content of the file is in the DB?

Comment: I your real question is not about binary data per se but about determining the file type of the data, I'd recommend to have a look at the [ruby-filemagic gem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901660/1544012) which will give you this information much more reliably.

Comment: @BoraMa, are you saying I need to write the file content to a file, then feed the file path into FileMagic, and it will tell me what type of file I have?

Comment: @Dave According to the gem's documentation at https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic it can work with a buffer, so you wouldn't need to write anything to a file. Just read the first N bytes into memory and pass it to the gem.

Comment: But does this gem work with Rails 5?  I'm getting a "Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension" when I try and install it.

Comment: I adopted my recommendation into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your real question is not about binary data per se but about **determining the file type of the data**, I'd recommend to have a look at the [ruby-filemagic gem](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) which will give you this information much more reliably. The gem is a simple wrapper around the libmagic library which is standard on unix-like systems. The library works by scanning the content of a file and matching it against a set of known "magic" patterns in various file types.

Sample usage for a string buffer (e.g. data read form the database):

```
require "ruby-filemagic"

content = File.read("/.../sample.pdf") # just an example to get some data

fm = FileMagic.new
fm.buffer(content)    
#=> "PDF document, version 1.4"
```

For the gem to work (and compile) you need the `file` utility as well as the `magic` library with headers installed on your system. Quoting from the readme:

> The file(1) library and headers are required:
>
> Debian/Ubuntu:: +libmagic-dev+
>   Fedora/SuSE::   +file-devel+
>   Gentoo::        +sys-libs/libmagic+
>   OS X::          brew install libmagic

Tested to work well under Rails 5.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still getting a build error when I try and install this gem -- "checking for -lgnurx... no, *** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module".  I will have to research that and then come back and try your suggestion.

Comment: What system are you trying this on? If you get stuck, can you post the full log with the error messages?

Comment: I hadn't run "brew install libmagic" per your suggestion.  Running that does allow everything to install.  One question I coudln't figure out from teh docs -- does "buffer" always print out file types in a consistent way?  That is, do Excel docs always output "Microsoft Excel" and PDF docs always print out the word "PDF" ?

Comment: Good! Regarding your question, there isof course no absolute certainity, but I'd expect the output to be very consistent. The `file` utility with the associated `magic` library have been around for many many years and there is no reason that the authors would change its behavior. Take a look at the [sources](https://github.com/threatstack/libmagic/tree/master/magic/Magdir) for all the format variants that the library currently recognizes.

Comment: Heya, I started a bounty on this one only because I can see no consistency in the way file types are printed out by this gem.  I'm getting too much variation to feel comfortable using the solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give an example of the variation?

Comment: look at the source of the gem then, if you do you'll see it's basically just a wrapper around what your system is identifying. So your problem is with the system utilities that identify the [Magic Byte](https://blog.netspi.com/magic-bytes-identifying-common-file-formats-at-a-glance/) of the file and not the gem itself. Basically, you've stumbled on one of the dark magic areas of computing, i.e. it's hard to determine file type accurately.

Comment: @engineerDave yeah, that's why I recommended to look at the library sources above. There are hundreds of formats and their variants recognized by the library. If you need to support only a few of them then it would make sense to use such library, if you need something more general (like "all binary formats") then you'd indeed need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an unix machine, you can use the *file* command:

```
file titi.pdf
```

You could then do something like:

```
require 'open2'

cmd = 'file -'
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, wait_thr|
  stdin.write(content)
  stdin.close
  puts "file type is:" + stoud.read
end
```

Comment: My production environment is Ubuntu Linux, but my local environment is Mac OS X.