# Call a ruby script from within a rails app controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to rails and I have a script that I run from the console like this

```
   $ ruby axml2xml.rb ExamPaper.apk
```

Now, how do I call this script from within my controller method and pass the same parameter as `ExamPaper.apk`?

I tried `require 'axml2xml.rb'` but got some error pointing to this line of code `Zip::ZipFile.foreach(ARGV[0]) do |f|`. So basically, how do I make something like `axml2xml.rb 'ExamPaper.apk'` in my controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least 3 options:

- `exec(command)`
- `%x{ command }`
- `system(command)`

They have different behaviors, so make sure to read [this quicktip](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands) and/or the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby) to learn more about these commands.

In your case, the backticks or `%x` command is probably the best option.

```
value = `ruby axml2xml.rb ExamPaper.apk`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `system` or `popen`, but only for short tasks, for more information about that, please see [here](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/).

If your task is more time consuming you definitely should have a look at something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and use a background job or some sort of queue to run your job. This way your server doesn't get blocked and your users do not have to wait til your job completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute it as a shell command, use:

```
exec 'ruby axml2xml.rb ExamPaper.apk'
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby there are several ways to run shell commands.

```
system("ls")
%x("ls")
`ls`   #nice they are back ticks
exec "ls"
```

But I'm not sure about the permissions necessary for running commands like that via rails.