# using grep in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, grep

I have a simple script that scrapes a webpage and puts the lines of content to the screen, then I simply pipe it to grep to output what I want then pipe that to less.

```
myscript.rb scrape-term | grep argument | less
```

I changed the script to use the following, instead of having the extra arguments on the command-line;

```
%x[ #{my-text-output} | grep argument | less ]
```

but now I get the error;

```
sh: 0: command not found
```

I've tried the other variants found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby) but nothing works!

Comment: is #{my-text-output} a bash command to execute or the actual text you want to parse?

Comment: You could always do the `grep` inside your script. Using `String#match` isn't that tricky.

Comment: it's a method call that outputs the text that's to be parsed

Comment: You can't do it that way. That expands to a shell command to be executed. If you can't run what that expands to on the shell independently, it probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is open a handle to `grep`, not jam the output into there. The hack solution is to dump your output in a Tempfile and read from that through `grep` but really that's a mess.

Ideally what you do is only emit output that matches your pattern by filtering:

```
while (...)
  # ...

  if (output.match(/#{argument}/))
    puts argument
  end
end
```

Then this can be channelled through to `less` if required.

Remember there's also a `grep` method inside of Ruby for anything in an Array. For example, if you've created an array called `output` with the lines in it:

```
output.grep(/#{argument}/).each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use the system's grep for the flags I use, namely -A and -B

Comment: You can do this within Ruby if you buffer all the output in advance. The `each_with_index` method provides line numbers that can be used to extract ranges of entries. If you don't want to bother with this, use a `Tempfile` and fire that through your `grep | less` pipe.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're going to run it in a shell anyway, because of a `less` command, then maybe try this:

```
%x[ echo #{my-text-output} | grep argument | less ]
```

You can also try to do `echo -e` which will display `\n` as newline etc.

*(Ideally, your text should have a `\n` char at the end of each line already.)*

**Edit:**

Forgot about `""` for variable. No more `Unknown Command` errors, although `less` doesn't want to work with me. I have this script.rb now:

```
text = "foo
foobar
foobaraski
bar
barski"

a = %x[ echo "#{text}" | grep foo]

print a
```

And it gives me:

```
shell> ruby script.rb 
foo
foobar
foobaraski
```

**Edit 2:**

And now it works:

```
text = "foo
foobar
foobaraski
bar
barski"
system "echo '#{text}' | grep foo | less"
```

Opens up less with three lines, just as bash command would.

Comment: My bad @raphael_turtle - mix up with `"` - see edit 2. If this isn't what you want, then I don't uderstand the question.