# Use web app on linux server to run script

Tags: linux, perl, bash, web-applications

I have a bash and perl script in a file located on a linux server instance running on AWS. I am attempting to put a web application on that same server that would server as a GUI to run that script. (I.E. put a button on a web page that, when clicked, would run the script located on the same server but in the bin directory)

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @mob I feel like it was self explanatory without a question.

Comment: @tjameson I have tried using php and now I am working on using cgi. I have a bash script with some perl embedded that creates site directories each time it is run. Now I am trying to make  gui site for a user to click a button to run that script without having to ssh into the server

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a webserver setup in your language of choice, make a handler for your request of choice. Once that's done, Google `exec <language>`, where <language> is the language you're writing it in. Here are references for a few popular languages:

- [Go](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)
- [Javascript (node.js)](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)
- [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
- [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)
- [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your server is setup and there's a possibility that the apache user might not have correct permissions to run some commands but like most programming languages like php have a command for running external commands.

Checkout - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Install a HTTP server
Step 2: Configure the server to handle certain files in a certain directory as CGI scripts.
Step 3: Add a `<form>` to your page that `POST`s to a CGI script. Include a `submit` button. This isn't really a web-appy thing, running scripts on servers is ancient. See the guestbooks and counter-images of 90s webpages.

The script itself would look something like (in Perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;

# the following line is *strongly* recommended
use strict; use warnings; use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header();
exec "/usr/bin/script-I-want-to-run", "--switch", "value";
```

In Bash this *might* work:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
/usr/bin/script-or-whatever --switch value
```

Perl's [CGI module](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.63/lib/CGI.pm) will even help you with getting `$cgi->param`eters and stuff and can be absolutely recommended. You will find a lot of (mostly bad) tutorials on Perl CGI scripting in the interwebs when you ask Google. Read them anyway.