# How to run a shell script from silverlight application?

Tags: .net, linux, silverlight, shell

I am  devlopping a silverlight application (c#)  and i need to run a shell script found in a  linux server  ?

can anyOne  Help me please ?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. However unless you give us more information on exactly what you want to achieve (i.e. what does this shell script do) I don't think anyone is going to be able to make any sensible suggestions.

Comment: you can use a cgi capable web server and run the script as cgi depending on what you are _actually_ doing

Comment: i'am trying to excute a Shell script which will run a program in a linux server machine  .  this program is developed with Code Saturne .The running script runcase will compile all files in the SRC
directory and link them with the existing libraries. Do so  calculations and bring outputs .

Answer (score 1):

[@technosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854703/how-to-run-a-shell-script-from-silverlight-application#comment20835036_14854703) is right. You can use cgi(perl, ruby, etc.), or simple http(s) requests to your server. Like: `http://your-server-address/execute.php` and use php(or somthing else) command [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php) or ruby [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby), or what you want to handle your script output and send it to user.

---

**Example:**
*Application (ironruby):*

```
host = "your_server_address"
wclient = System::Net::WebClient.new
wclient.download_string_completed{|wc, e|
    # do something with e.Result
}
wclient_data.download_string_async(System::Uri.new("#{host}/get_users_dirs.php")))
```

*get_users_dirs.php:*

```
print shell_exec("bash ./get_users_dirs.sh");
```

*get_user_dirs.sh*

```
ls /home
```

---

Or you can develop your own ssh-client like a [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps running in `Out of Browser` mode is the answer you are looking for.

You can invoke COM from OOB where your Silverlight assembly is configured to run Out Of Browser with Elevated Permissions. From there you can do practically anything.

For example:

```
if (Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions && ComAutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
{
    dynamic cmd = ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    cmd.Run(@"c:\windows\notepad.exe", 1, true);
}
```

[This article will help with setting up your project](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/441/Silverlight-and-Desktop-NET-Integration.aspx)

`Also note that this will only work in Windows, hence the check for ComAutomationFactory.IsAvailable`

Comment: i'am trying to excute a Shell script which will run a program in a linux server machine from a client Side !