# Ruby equivalent of Python's subprocess.check_call/check_output

Tags: python, ruby, process, subprocess, pipe

Python provides two convenient functions for calling subprocesses that might fail, [`subprocess.check_call`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) and [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). Basically,

```
subprocess.check_call(['command', 'arg1', ...])
```

spawns the specified command as a subprocess, blocks, and *verifies that the subprocess terminated successfully* (returned zero). If not, it throws an exception. `check_output` does the same thing, except it captures the subprocess's stdout and returns it as a byte-string.

This is convenient because it is a single Python expression (you don't have to set up and control the subprocess over several lines of code), and there's no risk of forgetting to check the return value.

**What are the idiomatic Ruby equivalents to `check_call` and `check_output`?** I am aware of the `$?` global that gives the process's return value, but that would be awkward—the point of having exceptions is that you don't have to manually check error codes. [There are numerous ways to spawn a subprocess in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby), but I don't see any that provide this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple `check_call` I threw together, and that seems to work.

```
def check_call(*cmd, **kw)
  _, status = Process.waitpid2 Kernel.spawn(*cmd, **kw)
  raise "Command #{cmd} #{status}" unless status.success?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic/in-built methods are supplanted by the [POpen4](http://popen4.rubyforge.org/classes/POpen4.html) gem. And the [shell-executor](http://shell-executer.rubyforge.org/) gem provides further awesomeness.

Comment: I mentioned "awesomeness" purely on the functional value/benefit to the end user, and not based on where it comes from. But true, in the context of the original question – "idiomatic ruby equivalent" – it's a wrong answer, I didn't interpret the question correctly so it's fine to downvote the answer. Other than that, I have no clue what made you start personal attacks like "expectations low" or "not knowing good languages". This is not a language war here, nobody is comparing ruby and python, and that's completely not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's the most idiomatic solution in Ruby… but the one that's closest to Python is probably `Shell.execute!` from [`shell-executer`](http://shell-executer.rubyforge.org).

From the example on the docs page:

```
begin
  Shell.execute!('ls /not_existing')
rescue RuntimeError => e
  print e.message
end
```

Compare to:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call('ls /not_existing', shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print e.message
```

The most notable difference here is that the Ruby equivalent doesn't have a way to do `shell=False` (and take the args as a list), which Python not only has, but defaults to.

Also, Python's `e.message` will be a default message or something generated based on the return code, while Ruby's `e.message` will be the child's `stderr`.

If you want to do `shell=False`, as far as I know, you'll have to write your own wrapper around something lower level; all of the Ruby wrappers I know of (`shell-executer`, [`Popen4`](http://popen4.rubyforge.org/classes/POpen4.html), [`open4`][4]) are wrappers around or emulators of the POSIX `popen` functions.