# How to monitor specific folder and save content of each log file in that folder to mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rsyslog

We are developing a service for our QA staff.

The main goal is that a tester from our web interface be able to select from a github branch a dump for this particular machine and click "Deploy" button, then the rails app for testing will be deployed to Digital Ocean.

The feature I am now working on, is collecting deployment logs and displaying them through our web interface.

On DO droplet there is a "logs" folder which contains different log files which are populated during deployment:

`migrations_result_#{machine_id}.log`, `bundle_result_#{machine_id}.log`, etc.

Where `#{machine_id}` is the id of deployed machine on our service(it is not droplet id).

With the help of **remote_syslog** gem we are monitoring "logs" folders on each droplet and send them through udp to our main service server, and with the help of **rsyslog** we store them in a particular folder, let's say `/var/log/deplogs/`

So in `/var/log/deplogs/` we have:

migrations_result_1.log, bundle_result_1.log,

migrations_result_2.log, bundle_result_2.log,
   ...

migrations_result_n.log, bundle_result_n.log

How do I need to monitor this folder and save contents of each log file to mysql database?

I need to achieve something like the following (Ruby code):

```
Machine.find(#{machine_id}).logs.create!(text: "migrations_result_#{machine_id}.log contents")
```

Rsyslog does not seems to be able to achieve this. Or am I missing something?
Any advices?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English, I hope you can get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, congratulations! You are in front of a beautiful problem. My suggestion is to use divide and conquer.

Here are my considerations:

- Put the relevant folder(s) under version control (for example, GIT)
- Check via GIT commands the files that changed every X amount of time.
- Also obtain the differences between the prior version of each file, and the new ones, so you can update your database parsing the new info.

Just in case, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby) are ways to call system commands from ruby.

Hope that helps,