# How to run Gnuplot (.gp) file from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

I wrote a program in Gnuplot (a .gp file) to read data from a `.txt` file and plot scatter graph. How to write a program in Ruby env for running the `.gp` file? Should I put all the files in the same folder as well as the Gnuplot application folder? I'm not sure how to set the right path.

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you tried it? Running external executable code from Ruby as a sub-shell is easily done and is well documented here and on the Internet and in books. Open IRB and enter `%x[ls]` and press enter.

Comment: I would suggest you look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby) and make the same call to gnuplot you would make by hand.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try the ruby gem "gnuplot"? 
sometimes it is easier to use gnuplot directly, but gem gnuplot has helped me a lot too because i can directly put the data that i want to draw from my ruby program. 
i recommend you to have a try [gem gnuplot](http://rubygems.org/gems/gnuplot)

btw, if i'm not mistaken usually gnuplot read data from .dat file instead of .txt