# Call python script from ruby

Tags: python, ruby

For example, I can use Python scripts in PHP like there:

```
exec("python script.py params",$result);
```

where "script.py" - script name and variable `$result` save output data.

How I can make it with Ruby? I mean, call Python scripts from Ruby.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way would be [exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec).

```
result = exec("python script.py params")
```

Comment: I think it may be worth noting that using the `exec` function will replace the current running process with the command supplied. If, like me, you're looking for a way to invoke a helping shell command and capture the result, you should use another method (i.e. "maniacalrobot"'s answer below).

Comment: Using exec() will end the current process once running the python script is accomplished. Another way is to replace the use of exec with system. I used exec() in my Logstash configuration, and it ended the process, so as mentioned above by ChrisCorea, it is better to use another approach.

Answer (score 30):

You can shell-out to any shell binary and capture the response with backticks:

```
result = `python script.py params`
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do the same thing would be,

```
system 'python script.py', params1, params2
```

Comment: system 'python script.py', *[params1, params2]

Comment: You're not catching the result. And `system 'python', *["script.py", params1, params2]` is more accurate, I think.

Comment: Yes I know that, and I dont think it is even possible to catch the result through system function. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following python call from a ruby module.

In my case using `exec()` didn't work because it interrupts the current process and caused the simulation I was running to fail.

```
# run python script
`python #{py_path_py} #{html_path_py} #{write_path_py}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `backticks` to accomplish this in two ways

```
result = `python script.py params`
```

or

```
result = %(python script.py params)
```