# Execute scripts from my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following problem, I have to build a rails app which executes some script on my server machine and retrieves the output showing it to the user....I thought so, I create in my root app directory a directory called 'script' and I insert all my scripts, now how can I execute them and retrieve the output?
Thank you

P.S. Which linguage my scripts have to be written in to be executed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Bash Commands From Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back quotes ` like this:

```
@script_output = `my_script_path`
```

Ruby starts a new process, executes the script and returns the output

Comment: But do I have to put my scripts in a particular folder or just any is ok?

Comment: anywhere is ok, the 'my_script_path` is the full path of the script to be executed for example `bin\scripts\maintenance\create_backup.sh`