# How to bring system grep results into ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, grep

I'm currently grep-ing the system and returning the results into ruby to manipulate.

```
def grep_system(search_str, dir, filename)
   cmd_str ="grep -R '#{search_str}' #{dir} > #{filename}"
   system(cmd_str)
   lines_array = File.open(filename, "r").read.split("\n)
end
```

As you can see, I'm just writing the results from the grep into a temp file, and then re-opening that file with "File.open".

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should use `Shellwords.escape` to escape the arguments.

Comment: @Gumbo: Why kludge around the problem when there are tools that allow you to interact with external programs **without** invoking a shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never ever do anything like this:

```
cmd_str ="grep -R '#{search_str}' #{dir}"
```

Don't even think about it. Sooner or later `search_str` or `dir` will contain something that the shell will interpret in unexpected ways. There's no need to invoke a shell at all, you can use [`Open3.capture3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) thusly:

```
lines    = Open3.capture3('grep', '-R', search_str, dir).first
lines, _ = Open3.capture3('grep', '-R', search_str, dir)
```

That will leave you with a newline delimited list in `lines` and from there it should be easy.

That will invoke `grep` directly without using a shell at all. `capture3` also nicely lets you ignore (or capture) the command's `stderr` rather than leaving it be printed wherever your `stderr` goes by default.

If you use this form of `capture3`, you don't have to worry about shell metacharacters or quoting or unsanitary inputs.

Similarly for [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system), if you want to use `system` with arguments you'd use the multi-argument version:

```
system('ls', some_var)
```

instead of the potentially dangerous:

```
system("ls #{some_var}")
```

Comment: thanks for introducing me to open3.  I'm unfortunately on a Ruby 1.8.7 project that is impossible to upgrade, so I can't use open3 as you suggested here.

Comment: But you could use [`Open3.popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3): `Open3.popen3('grep', '-R', ...) { |stdin, stdout, stderr| ... }` and then read the relevant information from `stdout`.

Comment: nice, picking this as official answer then

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few better ways. The easiest is just to assign the result of invoking the command with backticks to a variable:

```
def grep_system(search_str, dir, filename)
   cmd_str ="grep -R '#{search_str}' #{dir}"
   results = `#{cmd_str}`
   lines_array =results.split("\n)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, meagar.  Unfortunately, system(cmd) just prints the results but returns "true". So "results" is set as "true", which doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. Use \`backticks\`

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  By the way, it's `\`#{cmd_str}\``.  I can't edit your answer, but this is for other people.

Comment: What happens when `search_str` or `dir` contain quotes or `dir` contains spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to pass an argument for the temporal filename. After all, writing and reading to/from a temporal file is something you should avoid if possible.

```
require "open3"
def grep_system(search_str, dir)
  Open3.capture2("grep -R '#{search_str}' #{dir}").first.each_line.to_a
end
```

Comment: What happens when `dir` contains a space or `search_str` contains a single quote?

Comment: Why bother with that nonsense when you can bypass the shell completely with `Open3.capture2('grep', '-R', search_str, dir)`? Or better, use `capture3` so that you can ignore `stderr`? Spend some time reviewing the CERT bulletins about Ruby, you'll see that many of them are about sloppy people that assumed that all the filenames and arguments they were passing to external programs were shell-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `system(cmd_str)`, you could use:

```
results = `#{cmd_str}`
```