# Using shell-like commands like "printf '*%.0s' $(seq 1 67)"

Tags: ruby, bash, printf

I'm using inside Bash Scripts that code to structure the output in sections:

```
    box_full() {
        printf '*%.0s' $(seq 1 67)
        echo ""
    }
    box_content() {
    echo -n "*"
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        printf ' %.0s' $(seq 1 65)
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
        RIGHT="$1"
        printf ' %.0s' $(seq 1 17)
        echo -n "${RIGHT}"
        printf ' %.0s' $(seq 1 $[48-${#RIGHT}])
    elif [ $# -eq 2 ]
    then
        LEFT="$1"
        RIGHT="$2"
        printf ' %.0s' $(seq 1 3)
        echo -n "${LEFT}"
        printf ' %.0s' $(seq 1 $[14-${#LEFT}])
        echo -n "${RIGHT}"
        printf ' %.0s' $(seq 1 $[48-${#RIGHT}])
    fi
    echo "*"
}`
```

The usage was:

```
box_full
box_content "Download-Process..."
box_full`
```

Is there any way to do this in Ruby Scripts?

EDIT: The first one i have solved through:

```
module Style
  def self.box_full
    puts '*' * 67
  end

  def self.box_content(content)
    box_rest = 66 - content.length
    box_rest.to_i
    print '* ' + box_rest * '' + '*'
  end
end
```

So box full works good.

For the second one i want to give a string called content to the method box content. Actually it doesn't work. The wished output is:

```
* content *
```

The last * should be set on the end of the line on place 67.
Is it possible to solve that in Ruby?

Comment: `$[ arith_expr ]` is undocumented. Use `$(( ... ))` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do that by making a system call in your ruby script:

```
system("printf '*%.0s' $(seq 1 67)")
```

If you ever need to reference a variable such as an input argument:

```
system("echo #{ARGV[0]}")
```

Comment: Sure. That was my idea too. I thought there is a more Ruby like solution.

Comment: Check this post actually:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby