# Revoke certificates by API

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I need to revoke x509 client certificates in Ruby. I can do so via the openssl command:

```
openssl ca -revoke certificate.pem
```

but there does not appear to be an API to do this, at least not in [Ruby's OpenSSL module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html).

Is there an API in OpenSSL or another tool (that runs on Linux) that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby).

```
%x( openssl ca -revoke certificate.pem )
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an API. Doing it via command line is worst case, as openssl will prompt for a password, etc.