# Convert large data dump file to a TSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a very large file (a data dump) that is a couple hundred million records. I need to build a TSV based off of that data dump file.

Columns are separated by "\001".

I am doing something like this:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open(tsv_path, 'w', col_sep: "\t") do |tsv|
  File.open(data, 'rb').each do |line|
    row = line.split("\001")
    tsv << row
  end
end
```

This is insanely slow. For a data dump file that has 200 million rows is takes an hour and 30 minutes.

Is there a quicker way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in Ruby? I would suggest using something like `sed` to do that job.

Comment: Well, I am using a Ruby program to do a lot of other work with the files. Would I be able to execute sed from within Ruby?

Comment: Sure. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd probably do this with sed or tr.  But if you're sticking with ruby, I wouldn't use the csv library.  All you're really doing is a search and replace on \001 with \t, which is basically a call to tr, ala

```
puts line.tr("\001", "\t")
```