# Ruby : get output of external command even when there is no line break

Tags: ruby, shell, external-process

I try to run an external command in Ruby, and parse its output .

```
 IO.popen(command, :err=>[:child, :out]) {|ls_io|
  ls_io.each do |line| 
   print line   
 end
 }
```

This way of doing it works wonders… except when I parse the progress-output of a c-program that shows it progress to stdout with \r.

As long as the c-program has not outputted a \n (that is as long as it has not finished some long-operation), Ruby waits and sees nothing. Then when a \n is outputted, Ruby sees it all

```
1%\r2%\r3%\r…100%
task finished
```

I tried all of the many ways to call external commands (eg [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)) ; but none seem to capture the progress. I also tried every opeartor such as `STDOUT.sync = true`, and the c-program does call `fflush(stdout)`

I finally found a workaroud. I do :

```
IO.popen(commande, :err=>[:child, :out]) {|ls_io|
while true
  byte=ls_io.read(1)
  if byte.nil?
    break
  end
   print byte
end
}
```

It's stupid… but it works.

Any more elegant way, and much more efficient way to do this ? Performance is terrible, as if the "refresh rate" was slow.

Answer (score 0):

Set the input record separator to "\r" right before your block (provided you know it in advance):

```
$/ = "\r"
```

Reference of global preset variables: http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#pre-defined-variables

Comment: thanks… but then there are also those \n I wanna catch. I just want to receive the output like I would if calling the command from a shell rather than from ruby !