# Python workers in Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, worker, ironworker

I'm building rails application, I have workers from other project, they called [ironworker](http://www.iron.io/worker) and written on Python. Is it possible to use this workers in Rails application?
As one of solution, I'm going to use other worker - [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), but can I execute Python scripts?

Thanks for help, I have no idea from what I should start

Comment: It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: @Veedrac
In this case, the input/output data does not matter. The goal is to preserving and execute Python scripts in Rails environment using workers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is geared towards specific, directly answerable questions with little scope for opinions and hints. If you really don't have any kind of example, I imagine there are more appropriate places to ask.

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks for answer. I'll take a look "more appropriate places to ask".

Comment: I don't understand why the OP is so reluctant to get specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from the docs of ironworker, python workers can be run from command line.

```
exec 'hello_worker.py'
```

This post explain how you can do it:
[Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby).

For example you can call python workers in your rescue worker:

```
class ImageConversionJob
  def work
    system("exec 'hello_worker.py'")
  end
end
```

Comment: It's exactly that what I need:)