# Run OS X `say` command inside a Ruby shell script without exiting

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, shell

How can I run the OS X command `say` ([man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html)) inside a Ruby shell script without exiting that script? The advice in the thread [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby) doesn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
`say "#{var_name}"`
```

If you find backticks hard to read

```
%x(say "#{var_name}")
```

This would work as well:

```
system "say", var_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
message = "Hello world"

`say "#{message}"`
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I do variable expansion with that? (e.g., `say variable_name`)