# How to use curl in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, request

I have curl str

```
 curl -L –user '61332:Ne5re3w34fa' -H «Content-Type: application/json» -d '{«confirmed_at»: {«date»:«2014-04-30», «period»: 30}, «merchant_id»:73, «state»:[3,4], «type»: 0, «sub_id»:«test»}' -X POST https://myurl/
```

which returns me data in console

But how to use it inside rails app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Bash Commands From Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby stdlib has opportunity to run system commands

Here is good review of all possible variants: [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby)

Also there is curl gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/curb