# Decrypting windows instance password

Tags: ruby, encryption, amazon-web-services, fog

I have created a Windows Instance on AWS through FOG gem, I get the password through:

```
connection.get_password_data(instance_id).body['passwordData']
```

This password is encrypted, base64-encoded password of the instance.

How to decode and decrypt this password.

As specified in AWS documentation that, the password is encrypted using the key pair that you specified when you launched the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it directly from the http://aws.amazon.com console, which will look like this:
[image]
but you can also do it thru the CLI if you have it installed:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-GetPassword.html

Edit: If you want to programatically decrypt a password, this may help: http://www.frontiertown.co.uk/2012/03/java-administrator-password-windows-ec2-instance/

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I want to fetch the decrypted password through FOG gem. I am not getting any way to fetch decrypted password through FOG gem.

Comment: Is there any way to decrypt the password programmatically?

Comment: See my edit, added link to article that shows you how to decrypt a password which may help.

Comment: Hey Brennan, Thanks for the answer.
Finally Got the solution:

https://github.com/tomrittervg/decrypt-windows-ec2-passwd

This helped me to decrypt the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt the password using:

- [AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38499769/55075)
- [AWS CLI](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3825/3) command-line tool, e.g.

  ```
  aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id i-instanceid --priv-launch-key mykey.pem
  ```
- OpenSSL command-line utility, e.g.

  ```
  printf 'BASE64ENCODEDSTRING==' | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey mykey.pem
  ```

In Ruby, you can use `system()` to invoke above commands. See: [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2232/55075)