# How to decrypt AWS Windows password without using AWS SDK?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2

I deployed a windows machine on AWS with a key pair.
I want the windows administrator password.

I got the windows encrypted password using:

```
var myEC2GetPasswordDataResult = ec2Client2.getPasswordData(myEC2GetPasswordDataRequest);

myEC2GetPasswordDataResult = myEC2GetPasswordDataResult.withInstanceId("instanceID");
System.log( myEC2GetPasswordDataResult.toString());

myEC2GetPasswordDataResult.getPasswordData()
```

Now how can I decrypt this password?

I tried many options with castlebouncy but none of them worked.

Comment: Related: [how to retrive aws-ec2 windows instance password using aws sdk in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499769/how-to-retrive-aws-ec2-windows-instance-password-using-aws-sdk-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i dont want to decrypt the password using AWS  SDK, my requirement is to decrypt it using JAVA and base 64. I know using the AWS sdk i can call the getDecryptedpassword method -but i cannot use that. I need a way to decrypt the password using java code but without sdk.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use [AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38499769/55075), another way to decrypt the password is to use OpenSSL.

Here is the example using command-line:

```
printf 'BASE64ENCODEDSTRING==' | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey mykey.pem
```

<sup>Related: [Windows Password won't decrypt on AWS EC2 even with the correct private key](https://serverfault.com/q/603984/130437).</sup>