# Executing commands in Shoes

Tags: ruby, rspec, shoes

Is it possible to execute an **rspec** command (usually executed in **Terminal**) using **Shoes**?

More detailed: I want to create some kind of GUI with a few buttons. Every button should execute a different command usually executed in **Terminal**.

So, I want to start my Shoes app -> click a button -> the button opens **Terminal** and executes a command (something like "*cd /Users/Documents/test*" and then "*rspec test_spec.rb*". I'm a Ruby and Shoes newbie, so if there is a better/easier way to do this for a newbie - please suggest.

OS: Mac OSX

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shoes is just a ruby program, so you can do whatever ruby does. So [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby) should hold your answers.

For instance this works and returns the result:

`` 2.2.2 :004 > `pwd`
 => "/home/tobi\n" ``

You can run the commands, capture the output and then display it in your shoes application anyway you like.