# Need to store output of `system`

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to store the output of `system` in a variable.

```
src_chksum =  'CertUtil -hashfile "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Wildlife.wmv" MD5'
print src_chksum
```

Output:

```
CertUtil -hashfile "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Wildlife.wmv" MD5
```

But the actual output is split across three lines:

```
MD5 hash of file C:\Users\abhishek.prusty\Desktop\wildlife.wmv:
d8 c2 ea fd 90 c2 66 e1 9a b9 dc ac c4 79 f8 af
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

When I use `system` before the backticks in the above code, only `True` was returned and stored. Thanks to question 8753691, I removed `system` and am only using the back ticks; I manage to store one line.

How do I do it when the output is split across multiple lines?

Comment: You do realize that in your code that you are setting `src_chksum` to the string containing your command, as such print it just shows your command without running anything.

Comment: But the backticks are supposed to execute the command and return the output as a string.. or am i wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract only md5 hash from that output you can use this:

```
src_chksum = `CertUtil -hashfile "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Wildlife.wmv" MD5`  #make sure you use the backticks instead of single quotation marks

md5_hash = src_chksum.split("\n")[1].gsub(' ', '')
```