# Logstash ruby filter and event fields

Tags: ruby, jruby, logstash

I am trying to capture IP address field from incoming logstash event and pass it on to a shell script to compare against a static black list. The issue is, I am able to print the IP addr using puts but not able to capture to pass it on to `system()` call in ruby filter. Here is my sample config.

I am using logstash 2.0

```
Sample input = {"name":"xyz", "source_ip":"8.8.8.8"}

input {

        stdin {
        codec => json
        }
}

filter {

        ruby {
        code => "
        # puts event['source_ip']  # This always works
        ip = event['source_ip']
        system('echo ${ip}')       # This echoes ${ip} instead of value !
        "
        }
}
```

I also tried '`echo #${ip}`' but it just prints `0`.

Comment: It doesn't answer your ruby question, but have you considered the translate{} filter?

Comment: I wasn't aware of translate{}, just looked at it. This is a good idea but a lot of other things in my conf file are already done using ruby filter which I think is more flexible. exec() and pipe() output plugins do not make sense in my use case. I would love to do this in ruby itself, I am sure it is something basic I am missing.

Comment: If you have time, it would be nice to edit your question to reflect the fact that newer versions of logstash do not support direct access to fields like your `event['source_ip']`. You can now access those fields using the accessor form: `event.get('source_ip')`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `system('echo ${ip}')` use below syntax to run shell commands:

```
puts `echo #{ip}`
```

[Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby)