# Redis Sorted Set: Bulk ZSCORE

Tags: ruby, redis

How to get a list of members based on their ID from a sorted set instead of just one member?

I would like to build a subset with a set of IDs from the actual sorted set.

I am using a Ruby client for Redis and do not want to iterate one by one. Because there could more than 3000 members that I want to lookup.

Here is the [issue tracker](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/2359) to a new command ZMSCORE to do bulk ZSCORE.

Comment: Consider using `MULTI`. There's no built-in multiple access for `ZSCORE`. Maybe indicate the language of your choice so this may be answered in a more specific way.

Comment: @woozyking I am using Ruby client. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: You can use `MULTI` with Ruby, can't you?

Comment: @Jordan I am using redis-objects, not sure how to do multi with that

Comment: You can use `MULTI`, and other exposed features provided by `redis-rb` which is what `redis-objects` depends on. You can actually use `pipeline` which may be fater than MULTI, provided your use case is simple enough https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#pipelining . Otherwise Lua scripting may be more powerful and overall efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variadic form for `ZSCORE`, yet - see the discussion at: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2344

That said, and for the time being, what you could do is use a Lua script for that. For example:

```
local scores = {}
while #ARGV > 0 do
    scores[#scores+1] = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], table.remove(ARGV, 1))
end
return scores
```

Running this from the command line would look like:

```
$ redis-cli ZADD foo 1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d
(integer) 4
$ redis-cli --eval mzscore.lua foo , b d
1) "2"
2) "4"
```

**EDIT:** In Ruby, it would probably be something like the following, although you'd be better off using [`SCRIPT LOAD`](http://redis.io/commands/script-load) and [`EVALSHA`](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) and loading the script from an external file (instead of hardcoding it in the app):

```
require 'redis'

script = <<LUA
    local scores = {}
    while #ARGV > 0 do
        scores[#scores+1] = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], table.remove(ARGV, 1))
    end
    return scores
LUA

redis = ::Redis.new()
reply = redis.eval(script, ["foo"], ["b", "d"])
```

## Lua script to get scores with member IDs:

```
local scores = {}
while #ARGV > 0 do
    local member_id = table.remove(ARGV, 1)
    local member_score = {}
    member_score[1] = member_id
    member_score[2] = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], member_id)
    scores[#scores + 1] = member_score
end
return scores
```

Comment: can we run lua script using a ruby client instead of cli?

Comment: @emaillenin you can run shell command within ruby http://stackoverflow.com/a/2400

Comment: @emaillenin - of course, just call redis-rb's `redis.eval()` (or `redis.evalsha()`)

Comment: @ItamarHaber have added the lua script to return scores along with member IDs just like `with_scores` option. Don't know lua programming, so it might look naive :)

Comment: As long as it does the job you want it to do - anything goes ;)