# How do I run a non system command in ruby?

Tags: ruby

We have an automation script which we run in Windows command prompt.

We use it like 'Automate task 1'

Now I am trying to run it using ruby. I followed [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby) post.
But since this is not a system command it doesn't get executed.

```
system('Automate task 1')
```

How do I excute such commands?

Note: We don't have access to type or source of that command nor knows where is the command stored. We just execute it in cmd.

Comment: Enter the full path to the executable.

Comment: U didn't read my note.

Comment: "System command" doesn't mean much. but if whatever program you're trying to run is **NOT** findable via the underlying OS's $PATH, %PATH, etc... then you MUST provide the full absolute `/path/to/whatever/Automate`

Comment: @InQusitive Then you'll need to add the path to it as an environmental variable. You have to specify the location somehow.

Comment: You don't know where the command is stored? Sounds like something you should figure out first.

Comment: @MarcB: There are many paths in my PATH variable, I know one of them is the automation path but don't know which. Still do I need to give the path in the ruby script? Can't it take from PATH variable/? Anyway it works in cmd.

Comment: @Darkwater: Consider I have the path , for eg: C:/scripts . Now how do I excecute it?  system('C:\Scripts\Automate task 1') ??

Comment: @InQusitive I have little experience with Ruby on Windows but I'd suspect so, yes. At least that's how it'd work on Linux.