# Find declared function from user input

Tags: ruby, parsing, irb

I have a prompt in my "app", like `irb` that takes an input,I want it to parse the input and execute a function that I've defined.
Similarly, my app takes an input through `gets`, and calls the function.
For example,

```
command = gets.gsub("\n","")
```

takes an input `"pwd"`, now I want to call the function `pwd`, which is defined below:

```
def pwd
  Dir.pwd
end
```

Now, I could simply use `if` conditions to do so, but a lot of these conditions wouldn't be as elegant as Ruby's philosophy requires it to be.

**The Question**

I want to parse the input to call a defined function.
Like, `"pwd"` calls `pwd`,
`"ls"` calls its equivalent function that I have defined.

How do I do this?
Comment if question is still not clear.
Cheers.

**Addressing Possible Duplicate**

The question suggested specifically wants to run **Shell** commands. Whereas, I am using only built-in Ruby methods and classes and maybe in the future I'll even use Gems, so as to attain platform independence. My commands may look and behave like shell, but I'm not actually running shell. Therefore, my question is not a possible duplicate.

Furthermore, future readers will find it helpful for parsing input in Ruby.

Comment: Where is `ls` defined in Ruby?

Comment: It isn't. That's the point. I made my own function and I'll call it using "ls"

Comment: So if the command is "pwd", then Ruby should call `Dir.pwd` and if the command is "ls", then Ruby should call your own `ls` method. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Oh, you've edited your question. Is there a class that has a method with the same name for each command?

Comment: No. I just have `pwd.rb`, `ls.rb` etc, and I `require` them. Will it help if there are classes for these functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling shell commands from Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a mapping for the different inputs in the form of a case:

```
case command
when "pwd"
  Dir.pwd # or move it into another method and call it here
when "ls"
  # etc
end
```

or a hash, which is slightly more concise

```
actions = {
  pwd: -> { Dir.pwd },
  ls: -> { <foobar> } 
}
actions[command.to_sym].call
```

You can also make method names matching the commands and use `send`, but don't do this if the input is coming from strangers:

```
def pwd
  Dir.pwd
end

command = command.to_sym
send(command)
```

Comment: I'm already on the third approach. However, command is a string. `to_sym` will only make, for example `:"pwd"`

Comment: Yes, what is wrong with that? You pass a symbol to `send`, `:"pwd"` is a symbol.

Comment: But that wont call `pwd`, will it?

Comment: yes, `send(:pwd)` will call the `pwd` method you've defined.