# shell folder move to upper folder

Tags: shell, debian

I am total new to shell scripting.
I have to write a  script that moves every file/folder to the folder above.

```
d/doc/new_x/x

d/doc/new_y/y

d/doc/new_z/z
```

`x,y,z` should be moved to `d/doc/`

`x,y,z` can be folders or files

```
for d in */; do
  mv $d /.
done
```

I'm unsure of how to move the directories to the folder above.

Edit:
Sorry made mistake in foldernames

its

d/doc/new_x/x and x has to be moved to d/doc

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Run in your directory (folder):

```
mv  -v ./* ../
```

This will move all the files and directories to the upper directory.

Comment: Wouldn't `mv * ..` be sufficient?

Comment: sorry made a mistake in foldername its new_x