# run git from within ruby script

Tags: ruby, git, commit

I want to dave or change a file with ruby, thats no problem. But this file is part of a git repository that needs to be commited after the change. How can I achieve that with the ruby script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call a shell command in your ruby script.  There are lots of ways to execute a shell command in ruby.  Backticks are one of them.  Look at this [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby) for more.

```
`git commit -am "Committing from ruby script"`
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Git library like `ruby-git`- establish the repo in a temp folder, pull the project into it, change the file, commit it, push it, and delete the repo. (Assuming it's a rare operation. If not, you should probably establish a permanent repo folder and just keep pulling, committing, and pushing it.)

Comment: the git repo is already there on the server where I wants to run the ruby script, I dont need to push, just commit.