# Get serial number from a certificate using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, x509certificate, der

Is there a way to know a certificate serial number with Ruby? I know I can get it by using:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in file.cer -noout -serial >"serial.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly run shell commands in ruby and `gets` its output to a variable. I assume you will have to do something along the line of:

```
serial = `openssl x509 -inform DER -in file.cer -noout -serial`
```

Here is a more detailed answer: [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby)

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot, I was able to run it with the full path of file but I don't know how to run it with a variable (to use it on every file). 

i used this:

serial = `openssl x509 -inform DER -in /home/faviovelez/webapps/projects/007/mosaicone007/lib/cer/2/LAN7008173R5.cer -noout -serial` 

and got this:

"serial=3230303031303030303030333030303232383135\n"

Do you know how can I run it with a variable that I can replace with the filename and path to it?

Comment: Got it! I just did this:

file = File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.cer')
serial = `openssl x509 -inform DER -in #{file} -noout -serial` 

And got the answer I needed! Thanks a lot! @Ziyan Junaideen

Answer (score 1):

There is module `OpenSSL` in standard library, which includes class [OpenSSL::X509::Certificate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html), with method `#serial`

Comment: Thanks, I used this:  

new_file = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.cer'))  translate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new new_file 

but got this:  

#<OpenSSL::X509::Certificate: subject=#<OpenSSL::X509::Name:0x005603888a9ee0>, issuer=#<OpenSSL::X509::Name:0x005603888a9f58>, serial=#<OpenSSL::BN:0x005603888a9f80>, not_before=2016-10-25 21:52:11 UTC, not_after=2020-10-25 21:52:11 UTC> 

but when I run the command in shell I got:

serial="serial=3230303031303030303030333030303232383135" (thats the expected result)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. Now you got your certificate object in variable `translate`. Did you call `translate.serial`? What did you received?

Comment: Yes, and I got => #<OpenSSL::BN:0x0055747e71bd88> but solved with:

file = File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'cer', '2', 'LAN7008173R5.cer') 
serial = openssl x509 -inform DER -in #{file} -noout -serial

and got this: "serial=3230303031303030303030333030303232383135\n"