# run php script in ruby on rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

hi can help me on the process to run a php file in ruby on rails application?

actually i want to use a php script when I run some rails url but i want to know if its posible and how can i do that,

obviously I want to conect to the database when I run the script and modify multiple table

or maybe ccan help to provide a rails exampel to update multiple tables once when I create a record

actually this is mycontrroller i hpe that i need to add the script on the controller but i don know please tel me if is poble to add php script or how can I update multiples tables

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
    render json: @comments
  end
  def show
    render json: @comment
  end

  # POST /comments
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment
    else
      render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :comment)
    end
end
```

Comment: You can update multiple tables in rails, there is nothing stopping you from doing that, you need to provide more context in your question about what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Kernel#exec` function to call another scripts in the SO.

Example:

`exec( "php /foo/bar/script.php" )`

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby) can help you. Hope it helps.

More info about the Kernel module:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html