# How to open xterm and display in this xterm from a ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I would like to open a terminal from my ruby script, display the script outputs and exit the terminal at the end of the script.

```
# open xterm -> `mate-terminal -e " ... "`
a = ''
while a != 'q'

  a = STDIN.getch

  puts "Hello World !" # output in xterm
end

# quit xterm
```

Is this possible or do I have to do a script to call another one?

**EDIT:**

I can do with two scripts :

test1.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
`mate-terminal -e "bash -c 'ruby test2.rb'"`
```

test2.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "hello world"
gets
```

run first script

```
$ ruby test1.rb
```

But is it possible to do this with a single script?

**EDIT2 :**
I try to do that

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
obj1 = "object 1"
obj2 = "object 2"

file = <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'io/console'
a = ''
while a != 'q'
    puts "Do you want to see obj1, obj2 or quit ? .. enter 1, 2 or q"
    a = STDIN.getch
    case a
    when '1' then puts "#{obj1}"
    when '2' then puts "#{obj2}"
    end
end
EOF

File.open('display.rb', 'w') { |f| f.puts file }

`mate-terminal -e "bash -c 'ruby display.rb'"`
```

It works, but it's really not beautifull.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to fork your current process? Not sure what you mean by => "display the script outputs". Which script?

You'll want to read this post.
[Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby)

You might want to check IO.popen. You'll note, in the code below, that we first pipe the string whoami to the shell and then pass the string whoami to puts.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

if __FILE__ == $0

  f = IO.popen("bash", "w")
  f.puts "whoami"
  f.close

  puts "whoami"

end
```

output

```
gerard
whoami
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Have you explored IO.popen? https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.popen

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for. I want to run a script in the background ( like a daemon ) to display specific information through a terminal ( like a popup ).

Comment: This is very important. Do you want to pass a one time message or one command to the terminal or do you want to have a connection between the background process(daemon) and the terminal(shell) that you can continue to update?

Comment: Yes, I want a connection between the background and the terminal. I want to be able to choose the information displayed.

Comment: The thing is, I think you want a connection to the shell. If you need to display the shell results to the user, then you should use a GUI toolkit like Tk. I might be wrong but I don't think you can form that connection: process => terminal => shell... I should clarify, I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: I want to do ruby_process => terminal => ruby_process instead. But maybe it's above my level. I have to learn more first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why the terminal(a terminal is just a GUI wrapper around a shell(bash in some cases)) is in that equation. Why not have a ruby_process which spawns another ruby_process? Why do you need that middle step?