# How do I use git command in my ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

The command is

```sh
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log --since="90 days ago" -1 --format="%e {}" {} | sort > name.txt
```

I want to fetch file names from a git repo from last 90 days and store it in a file say, `name.txt`.

How do I use this command in my script ?

```rb
Git.clone('https://github.com/visual-diff/visual-app.git','C:\visual_app')
path = 'C:\visual_app'
command='git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log --since="90 days ago" -1 --format="%e{}" {} | sort > date.txt'
contentsArray=[]
f = File.open("C:\\visual_app\\date.txt", "r")
f.each do |line|`enter code here`
    contentsArray.push line.chomp
end
f.close
print contentsArray
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/how-to-call-shell-commands-from-ruby

Comment: https://github.com/libgit2/rugged

Comment: https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git and so on