# How to transfer arguments to around_perform from perform in ActiveJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, python-3.x, rails-activejob

I want to run a python application in my Rails server with ActiveJob, but how can I transfer words that python application output to command line to around_perform in perform? I need to get result from the python application in around_perform.

```
  def perform(argument)
    cmd = "python3 " + argument + "/main.py "
    system cmd
  end

  private

  around_perform do |job, block|
    block.call
    puts "ActiveJob Done"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

See the docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-around_perform

it's `job.arguments` or `job.arguments.first` in your case.

Comment: I know that, but job.arguments refers to argument I pass into perform. And what I need are the words output by my python application：`system cmd`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/how-to-call-shell-commands-from-ruby . You should not be using system if you want to access the output from your command.